# PHP accessing property inside multi-dimensional array, which has an outer array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have one array that I am foreaching over:

```
array:8132 [
  0 => {#551
  "address_id": "94e224af-135f-af31-3619-535acfae9930"
  "fiber_phase": "101"
  "parsed_hash": "1bc7fb114ee10d7cb9cea10693d238b5"
  "min_number": 400
  "max_number": 499
  "sales_rep": "164"
  "id": "abd90d6b-28a8-2be6-d6c1-abd9007aef38"
  "name": "48TH ST E"
  "block_minimum": 400
  "block_maximum": 498
}
```

Inside the foreach, I have another array, that I need to access certain properties for an if statement that will then add a new property to the original array ($data):

```
foreach ($data as $phase) {
        $all_phases = EmeraldFiber::getPhases();
        dd($all_phases);

        if ($phase->fiber_phase === $all_phases[1]['name']) {
            $phase->fiber_status = $all_phases[1]['fiber_status'];
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

The `dd($all_phases);` looks like this:

```
array:270 [
  1 => array:7 [
    "id" => "10bc06d0-05de-07e2-b2de-5214fba5045a"
    "name" => "1"
    "description" => "50th France"
    "encoded_points" => "_sbqGnesxPJwv@iJBKpv@fJ@"
    "fiber_status" => "Live"
    "status_date" => "2010-09-01 00:00:00"
```

]

With the above foreach, I am only getting the original array returned, without the new property `fiber_status`. Am I not returning it correctly? Or do I need to map over the second array ($all_phases) to access those properties properly?

Comment: use refrence `foreach ($data as &$phase)`

Comment: `$all_phases = EmeraldFiber::getPhases();` does not depend on `$phase`. It should stay outside the `foreach`.

Comment: Your return will effectively stop the `for each` in its track after 1 iteration.

Comment: I suppose that `name=1` does not equal `phase_fiber=101`

Comment: There are many matches for `$phase->fiber_phase === $all_phases[1]['name']`

Comment: @Coreus how would you suggest returning?

Comment: Build up your sub arrays in the inner loop and have it update a variable you have declared earlier after the loop finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you don't need to `return` anything:

```
// receive object once instead receiving of it multiple times
$all_phases = EmeraldFiber::getPhases();
// extract required values
$phase_name = $all_phases[1]['name'];
$phase_status = $all_phases[1]['fiber_status'];

foreach ($data as $phase) {
    if ($phase->fiber_phase === $phase_name) {
        $phase->fiber_status = $phase_status;
    }
}

// if you have this code in a function - return data here
// otherwise - you don't need return
// return $data;
```

**Update:**
If `$all_phases` is **array** with all available phases and you need to check if `$phase->fiber_phase` is among them, then you should do the following:

```
// receive object once instead receiving of it multiple times
$all_phases = EmeraldFiber::getPhases();
// create pairs
$phase_names = [];        
foreach ($all_phases as $item) {
    $phase_names[$item['name']] = $item['fiber_status'];
}

foreach ($data as $phase) {
    // check if `$phase->fiber_phase` exists in `$phase_names`
    if (isset($phase_names[$phase->fiber_phase])) {
        // if it does - add it's value to `$phase` object
        $phase->fiber_status = $phase_names[$phase->fiber_phase];
    }
}
```

Comment: That exact code returns the original array, unaffected :/

Comment: Is `$phase` array or object? Add debugging - check values of variables, make sure that `if` condition is met somewhere.

Comment: $phase is an object

Comment: To clarify, there are many phase_name matches in the original $data array and I'm trying to inject the fiber_status property into the $data array if and where there is a phase_name/fiber_phase match.

Comment: Did you do a debug? Did you make sure your `if`statement met?

Comment: I do not know how to do that, but it clearly hasn't met. I believe with the above code, it is only checking against a single $phase_name and $phase_status. In this case, the first $phase_name is actually not in the original $data array. I need to check against all 270 phase names.

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to php and multi-dimensional arrays are still screwing me up.

Comment: That wipes the original array. What's this line ($phase_names[$item['name']] = $item['status'];) attempting to do? Did you mean $item['fiber_status']? When I make that change, it repeats the same object over and over, but with the fiber_status actually included and accurate.

Comment: It is inited as empty array, how can it be null.

Comment: Actually, yes it is returning empty.

Comment: It's working now, with `$phase_names[$item['name']] = $item['fiber_status'];`. Thanks!